# Use StringIO as stdin with Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following shell script that I would like to write in Python (of course `grep .` is actually a much more complex command):

```
#!/bin/bash

(cat somefile 2>/dev/null || (echo 'somefile not found'; cat logfile)) \
| grep .
```

I tried this (which lacks an equivalent to `cat logfile` anyway):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import StringIO
import subprocess

try:
    myfile = open('somefile')
except:
    myfile = StringIO.StringIO('somefile not found')

subprocess.call(['grep', '.'], stdin = myfile)
```

But I get the error `AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'`.

I know I should use `subprocess.communicate()` instead of StringIO to send strings to the `grep` process, but I don't know how to mix both strings and files.

Comment: You cannot use `StringIO` objects to provide process input; use `subprocess.PIPE` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters as I said (last sentence), "I know I should use subprocess.communicate() instead of StringIO to send strings to the grep process, but I don't know how to mix both strings and files."

Comment: Why not read from the open file object, write to the pipe? If there is no open file, write the alternative text.

Comment: Why not to use grep at all?

Comment: @Faust because in my case, the command is `gpg -weird -options -r recipients | mail -s subject recipients`, not just `grep`, and I want to send the e-mail in all cases, with a fallback when the body isn't found.

Comment: Oh, ok. You could do it in a full-pythonic way using some library. But I understand your point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '...'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, output_err = p.communicate(myfile.read())
```

Comment: Doesn't this read the whole contents of `myfile` into memory, allocate a string for it, etc.? Shouldn't there be a way to pass the file handle directly to the next process?

Comment: This will wait for the command to complete, won't it?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use bare `except`, it may catch too much. In Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_output

try:
    file = open('somefile', 'rb', 0)
except FileNotFoundError:
    output = check_output(cmd, input=b'somefile not found')
else:
    with file:
        output = check_output(cmd, stdin=file)
```

It works for large files (the file is redirected at the file descriptor level -- no need to load it into the memory).

If you have a file-like object (without a real `.fileno()`); you could write to the pipe directly using `.write()` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
from shutil import copyfileobj
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

try:
    file = open('somefile', 'rb', 0)
except FileNotFoundError:
    file = io.BytesIO(b'somefile not found')

def write_input(source, sink):
    with source, sink:
        copyfileobj(source, sink)

cmd = ['grep', 'o']
with Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) as process:
    Thread(target=write_input, args=(file, process.stdin), daemon=True).start()
    output = process.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Neat suggestion with `copyfileobj()`. Could you edit your answer to clarify, why a thread is required? I suppose it's required to avoid deadlocks while reading `process`es output.

Comment: @smbear what do you think would happen if a thread (or async. io) is not used?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer uses `shutil` as well --which is quite efficient--,
but avoids a running a separate thread, which in turn never ends and goes zombie when the stdin ends (as with the answer from @jfs)

```py
import os 
import subprocess
import io
from shutil import copyfileobj

file_exist = os.path.isfile(file)
with open(file) if file_exists else io.StringIO("Some text here ...\n") as string_io:
    with subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as process:
        copyfileobj(string_io, process.stdin)
        # the subsequent code is not executed until copyfileobj ends, 
        # ... but the subprocess is effectively using the input.

        process.stdin.close()  # close or otherwise won't end

        # Do some online processing to process.stdout, for example...
        for line in process.stdout:
            print(line) # do something
```

Alternatively to close and parsing, if the output is known to fit in memory:

```py
        ...
        stdout_text , stderr_text = process.communicate()
```