# Get output of `perl file.pl < some_file.txt` shell command

Tags: python, subprocess

```
output = cStringIO.StringIO()
output.write('string') # this emulates some_file.txt

p = subprocess.Popen(['perl', 'file.pl'], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
line, _ = p.communicate(output.getvalue())
print line
output.close()
```

This prints `Can't open perl script "file.pl": No such file or directory`. The python script and perl file are in the same directory!

I want `line` to be the output of `perl file.pl < some_file.txt`

How to do this?

Comment: is file.pl in the current working directory?

Comment: @ChadS.Yes, it is in the same directory. I have updated the question.

Comment: Your problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with `subprocess` and `cStringIO`. Try specifying an absolute path to `file.pl`.

Comment: _it is in the same directory_  doesn't really answer @ChadS. question about whether its in the current working directory. you could try `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'file.pl')` to explicitly look in the script's directory.

Comment: Why do you use `shell=True`? I think it is not needed here. If unsure don't use shell=True.

Comment: related: [Python: StringIO for Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20568107/4279)

Answer (score 0):

> I want line to be the output of `perl file.pl < some_file.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output

with open('some_file.txt', 'rb', 0) as file:
    line = check_output(['perl', 'file.pl'], stdin=file)
```

To fix `Can't open perl script "file.pl": No such file or directory`, pass the full path to `file.pl` e.g., if it is in the same directory as your Python script then you could use [`get_script_dir()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279), to get the path.